# How to call external function inside jquery code from html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I need to load function to get data from external JS included in HTML file, and I'm doing this:

```
<body onLoad="getTicket();">
......
</body>
```

or this:

```
<html>
<body>
    <head>
    <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/functions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            getTicket();
        });
    <script>
    </head>
<body>
</html>
```

or this:

```
<html>
<body>
    <head>
    <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/functions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        getTicket();
    <script>
    </head>
<body>
</html>
```

And I have this in functions.JS:

```
functioOne() {

}

functionTwo() {

}

$(document).ready(function() {
    ...
    .....
    function getTicket() {
        //to do
    }
});
```

But does'nt work and in the console display this:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: getTicket is not defined
```

Regards.

Comment: how are you including that external js file into that HTTML file ?

Comment: What browser are you using? Does it produce errors in your console? If there's a parsing error inside your functions.js file, the browser may 'skip' the rest of the file, causing your getTicket() function to 'not' being defined

Comment: The head tag has to be put before the body tag - especially when you want ```<body onLoad="getTicket();">```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `getTicket` function is defined only in the context (scope) of the jQuery closure (anonymous function). Define it in the global scope instead (elsewhere in the file and not as a "function parameter").

If you need variables from that scope, encapsulate them in a namespace (an object), or declare it as `window.getTicket = function() { /* ... */}`.

Answer (score 5):

Try putting the `function getTicket(){}` outside or the `doc ready`:

```
functio One() {

}

function Two() {

}
function getTicket() {
    //to do
}

$(document).ready(function() {
...
.....
   getTicket();
});
```

Your order of inclusion is perfect no issues with that.

```
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/functions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This is perfectly fine.

Comment: The problem is that getTicket() contains jQuery code and for that reason I can't put out.

Comment: There should not be any issues i think but you can try this though.

Comment: @SoldierCorp the document on ready part just makes sure that the DOM is populated before your jQuery runs.  You can define code outside of it, just so long as it isn't called yet.  (now whether or not you should is another question)

Answer (score 4):

you could do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  ...
  .....
  window.getTicket = function() {
    //to do
  } 
});
```

once the document is ready, you will be able to call getTicket

Comment: You mean, that I put that code in external js or in html file?

Comment: Thank you, your example helped to get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Add `<script type="text/javascript src="external.js"></script>` to `head`.

Then you have to wait for the document to be fully loaded.

The problem is that your code gets executed this way:

- execute external.js
- your function is not defined because the document hasn't finished loading
- you call the undefined function
- the document is ready

IMHO I don't think is a good idea to define a function inside $(document).ready. It would be simpler to normally define that function, then *call* it inside $(document).ready.

Comment: I -1'd you when your answer was just to "add the script tag" (which had nothing to do with the problem that the scope of the function was a closure, which means that he couldn't ever see it). Now you've edited it so I'm un-minus-oneing-it.

Answer (score 0):

You must include the js file before calling the function. If you do This:

```
<html>
<body>
    <head>
    <!-- include script files here.(jquery and custom script files) -->
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            getTicket();
        });
    </script>
    </head>
<body>
</html>
```

you must include your script file before calling the function.

Comment: Obviously that I have it, is the first thing you should do.